# What is the Differencce beetween www and a non-www version

Tags: google-search-console, no-www

I have recently launched my website for tutorials, and now I am working on the SEO. I have submitted the `sitemap.xml` file to Google Webmaster. Now, Google Webmaster Tools suggests to use either `www` or `non-www` version of my website (not both). Then i went through the several articles to choose the best among them. But some of them say that a `non-www` website don't have a CNAME record same articles say you must run your own server farms if I am using a `non-www` version.

What is a CNAME record and why will it create issue if I use a `non-www` version of my website?

Comment: There's too many questions here, some of which can be answered with a quick Google search. Do some research and see if you can whittle this down to something a little bit more manageable.

Comment: You are reading too much ****! Stop it!! ;-) Okay. If you have www and non-www now, then just chose one. It does not matter which one. Redirect the one you do not chose to the one you do chose. That is it. That is all you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome start sending Google your sitemap straight away - don't forget to update every few months if you are making minor changes to the structure of the site and straight after you do big changes to structure.

SEO questions. @closetnoc is right - stop reading. The internet has too many people saying the wrong thing about everything. There is no difference between www or non www. I would recommend the non-www if you plan to not have any subdomains in the future - its neat and short and its a pain to type the extra three characters when you don't have to.

CNAME issues and server farm questions: All untrue and likely not to effect you at all. I want to strongly stress that you don't need an expensive setup or expensive hosting to have www or non www. Someone is trying to rob you blind with that article.

CNAME is short for Canonical Name record - its a DNS record. It's used for aliasing names - which I highly doubt is reliant to you. It's more for people want to redirect there traffic to a different domain or make it appear as a different domain. Its a very rarely used setting for most web users and if you get to the stage that you are making DNS changed I'd recommend hiring a webmaster because getting it wrong is easy to do, and the results are bad especially if your website is serving lots of customers

NOTE: A subdomain is a domain like webmaster.stackoverflow.com where the top level domain is stackoverflow.com (just in case you needed a refresher)